# How to write "eval" and "apply" in this case?

Tags: scheme

Write the functions `eval1` and `apply1`.

`eval1` consumes an association list (where the key is *Symbol* and the value is *Num*) and an arithmetic expression, matching variable names to values.

`apply1` consumes a symbol (’+ or ’), a list of expressions,
and an association list, and computes the number resulting from applying the function
specified by the symbol to the expressions in the list.

Examples:

```
(check-expect (eval1 '((x 2) (y 3) (z 4)) '(+ x (* y 2))) 8)
(check-expect (apply1 '* '(a (+ 3 b)) '((a 2) (b 1))) 8)
```

PS: `eval1` and `apply1` should be mutual recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
(define (eval1 env exp)
  (cond ((number? exp) exp)
        ((symbol? exp)
         (cond ((assq exp env) => cadr)
               (else 'unbound-variable)))
        ((list? exp)
         (let ((operator (car exp))
               (operands (cdr exp)))
           (apply1 operator operands env)))))

(define (apply1 operator operands env)
  (case operator
    ((+) (+ (eval1 env (list-ref operands 0))
            (eval1 env (list-ref operands 1))))
    ((*) (* (eval1 env (list-ref operands 0))
            (eval1 env (list-ref operands 1))))
    (else 'unknown-operator)))
```

The important thing to recognize is that how you evaluate an expression depends on the nature of the expression.  If a number/literal, just return the number/literal; if a symbol, look up the value in the environment; if a list, apply the operator to the evaluated arguments.

Comment: Actually，I dont quite understand your code since I'm using the "intermediate student" language. Can u give me more hints?

Comment: Since I'm a starter of drracket and scheme, I can only use "intermediate student" language in drracket and I cant read some built-in ftn in your code like "car" or "cdr". What I want is using somthing like rescursion to deal with this question(Like base case empty)

Comment: Here is 'intermediate student with lambda' (http://bit.ly/Y1Mmiq); it has car, cdr, etc.  Your 'intermediate' is different?

Comment: Probably yes, I using only "intemediate student" language which is the language without lambda.

Comment: Well, since I've given you the answer to the hard part; I trust you'll be able to use the documentation for 'intermediate student with lambda' to find out what `car` etc mean.  Hint: car <==> first.